# Update temp table - tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, temp-tables

I've got a temporary work table that i need to update the sector value where the portfolio holds bonds and cash.  Currently in the work table i'll assign anything that is a bond to be "Bond" and anything to be cash to be "Cash".  I have an example table below:

```
PortfolioID    IssueClassification  Sector  Weight
AAA            020                  Bond    2.3
AAA            010                  Cash    1.5
AAA            030                  Equity  1.5
AAA            030                  Equity  5.5
AAA            030                  Equity  10.0
BBB            010                  Cash    7.0
BBB            030                  Equity  1.5
BBB            030                  Equity  2.5
```

So what i would like to update the worktable with, is if like portfolio AAA above holds both bonds and cash and i want to change its sector to "Cash and Bonds".  However if like portfolio BBB above it only holds cash and no bonds then the sector should remain as "Cash".  If a portfolio was to hold bonds but no cash then the sector should still change to "Cash and Bonds".  I've looked at ways of developing this during the insert into my #worktable but it would make the procedure far too inefficient.

So ultimately i want my above table to look like this:

```
PortfolioID    IssueClassification  Sector            Weight
AAA            020                  Cash and Bonds    2.3
AAA            010                  Cash and Bonds    1.5
AAA            030                  Equity            1.5
AAA            030                  Equity            5.5
AAA            030                  Equity           10.0
BBB            010                  Cash              7.0
BBB            030                  Equity            1.5
BBB            030                  Equity            2.5
```

I'm unsure of the update script that could best achieve this.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but I can't comment on the potential efficiency:

```
declare @a table (PortfolioID char(3),IssueClassification char(3),Sector varchar(93),  Weight decimal (5,2))
insert into @a(PortfolioID,IssueClassification,Sector,Weight) values
('AAA','020','Bond',  2.3  ),
('AAA','010','Cash',  1.5  ),
('AAA','030','Equity',  1.5  ),
('AAA','030','Equity',  5.5  ),
('AAA','030','Equity',  10.0 ),
('BBB','010','Cash',  7.0  ),
('BBB','030','Equity',  1.5  ),
('BBB','030','Equity',  2.5  )

update a1
set Sector = CASE
                WHEN Sector in ('Bond','Cash') AND
                    2 = (select COUNT(DISTINCT Sector) from @a a2 where a2.PortfolioID = a1.PortfolioID and Sector in ('Bond','Cash'))
                THEN 'Cash and Bonds'
                ELSE Sector
            END
from @a a1
```

Results:

```
select * from @a

PortfolioID IssueClassification Sector                  Weight
----------- ------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
AAA         020                 Cash and Bonds          2.30
AAA         010                 Cash and Bonds          1.50
AAA         030                 Equity                  1.50
AAA         030                 Equity                  5.50
AAA         030                 Equity                  10.00
BBB         010                 Cash                    7.00
BBB         030                 Equity                  1.50
BBB         030                 Equity                  2.50
```

It's hopefully quite easy to read and confirm that it's doing what is wanted - *if* the current value is Cash or Bonds, and *if* we can find both Cash and Bonds in this table for the same portfolio, then the `WHEN` clause is satisfied and we change the sector - otherwise we leave it alone

---

This could be simplified to:

```
update a1
set Sector = CASE
                WHEN 2 = (select COUNT(DISTINCT Sector) from @a a2 where a2.PortfolioID = a1.PortfolioID and Sector in ('Bond','Cash'))
                THEN 'Cash and Bonds'
                ELSE Sector
            END
from @a a1
where a1.Sector in ('Bond','Cash')
```

If this is the only transformation being applied, whereas the top query is a more general form for making multiple decisions about changes to `Sector`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this solve your problem:

```
SELECT PortfolioID, IssueClassification,
    CASE 
        WHEN Sector = 'Cash' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PortfolioTable WHERE PortfolioID = OuterTable.PortfolioID AND Sector = 'Bonds') THEN 'Cash and Bonds'
        WHEN Sector = 'Bonds' THEN 'Cash and Bonds'
        ELSE Sector
    END, Weight
FROM PortfolioTable AS OuterTable
```